# Generating new ids for table rows

Tags: jquery

I have developed an expand/collpase data grid where each TR will expand/collapse the child rows within. Also, it can create new TR's with child rows having the ability to expand/collapse using .live() function.

As of now, id's for the parent TR and child TD and hardcoded. Now i have to generate unique id for parent and child rows using jquery. How can i do that..?

Here is the implementation: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pixelfx/wJBgt/14/)

This is how expand/collapse works [Expand/Collapse logic](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/jquery/)

Thanks,
Ravi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a global counter, see [my update](http://jsfiddle.net/joshN/wJBgt/21/).

Comment: the counter is working, but i need to get expand/collapse also for the newly created rows. This is how expand/collapse works.

 1.Put a class of "parent" on each parent row (tr)
   2. Give each parent row (tr) an id
   3. Give each child row a class of "child-ID" where ID is the id of the parent tr that it belongs to

Comment: So i need to generate parent id and child-ID dynamically

Comment: @Nahom I updated the link. You can write place that variable wherever you need the id. As far as I understand this is all you wanted. If I was to do anymore, then I'd just rewrite the script the way I'd normally do an accordion, but that's not what you're wanting to learn, right?

Comment: the expand/collapse is working but having small issue here. Ids for the parent/child-row is nt binded correctly. For example, if i add 2 new rows the 1st parent row id is:[child1] and childrow class is: [child-row2]. and 2nd row parent id:[child2] and childrow class:[child-row3]. To make expand/collapse wrking correctly each child row should hav a class of "child-ID" where ID is the id of the parent tr that it belongs to...